# How Ubuntu detects the type of the hardware?

Tags: usb

I see, when I connect a mouse in usb, within seconds my mouse starts woking, similarly for pendrive it is mounted. I just want to know as its the same USB port, How do Ubuntu understands what type of device has been connected? I am asking this question because I have a wimax modem, but ubuntu seems not to get that. If I know how automatically ubuntu gets that, I may be able to manually start the modem. and BTW, I just need to know how they are recognized?

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions here - would you like help fixing the issue with the USB modem, understanding how Ubuntu interfaces with USB devices, or both? Please edit your answer accordingly... thank you (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB devices provide information describing what they are so the OS can automatically select an appropriate driver to communicate with the device.  If your modem does not work, it is probably because there is no Linux driver for it.